# How do I know what the hashing algorithm is for my BEP20 Token?

Tags: tokens, bsc, hash-algorithm

How do I find the hashing algorithm for the BEP20 Token that I created using remix.Ethereum? I am fairly new to the token world, but I managed to create a token. Here is the link to Bscscan if that is any help: https://bscscan.com/token/0xb7ebb0715a799e5a3749dbaaf6657c10c1da07d3

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hashing algorithm'? Ethereum uses keccak, a variation of SHA3, but supports others like sha256 and ripemd160.

Comment: Well, when you go to https://www.worldcoinindex.com/coinrequest to add a coin, it asks you what the coin’s hashing algorithm is. I was wondering what this would be for my BEP20 Token. Thanks.

Comment: It is better to ask the site's support. Other tokens like UNI do not have an hash algorithm. I'd leave it empty or add something like "N/A".